# How can I use HTML symbols like arrows in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that generates a list of `<form>` tags with multiple inputs and buttons inside. I want to use an arrow (↑) on a button but when I write

```
buttonUp.value="&#x2191;";
```

it doesn't work.
Instead of showing ↑, the button shows the raw code on the page.
How can I make the arrow display on the button?

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Unicode_escape_sequences).

`buttonUp.value = "\u2191";`

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend you do this with JavaScript (for newbies like me it's harder). It's very easy, using only html.

Example:

```html
<input type="submit" value="&#x2191; HELLO" style="border-radius:50px;" />
<button>&#x2191; HELLO</button>
```

If you still want to use js, the reply from guest271314 is working.

[Here is the list of symbols on HTML(click)](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

PS. I also recommend you use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io) , very nice icons.

Make sure to tell me if worked for you.

**I know this doesn't answer your question but I hope this will be useful for newbies**

Answer (score 1):

Use `button` element, which has `.innerHTML` property

```js
document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = "&#x2191;"
```

```html
<button></button>
```

alternatively, use the actual "upwards arrow" or "up arrow" character

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").value = "↑";
```

```html
<input type="button" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your solution code--it will only escape the first occurrence of each special character. For example:

```
escapeHtml('Kip\'s <b>evil</b> "test" code\'s here');
Actual:   Kip&#039;s &lt;b&gt;evil</b> &quot;test" code's here
Expected: Kip&#039;s &lt;b&gt;evil&lt;/b&gt; &quot;test&quot; code&#039;s here
```

Here is code that works properly:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

also u can use below code

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to escape html, they are trying to use an html entity in a button